# How can I make my reused quarter round trim miters fit?

Tags: carpentry

I am on a budget which means I am reinstalling the existing quarter round trim after putting in new floors.

I am sanding down and repainting the existing quarter round.

I laid out the quarter round (didn't fit them completely) and realized the miters are not tight in the corners.

Aside from just applying putty and sanding, what other tricks/solutions do the experienced contractors here have?

*If I sanded the miters down (the long and short points) a bit would that help it fit?*

Comment: Did you mark them as you were removing them so you could match them back again?  Were they tight before removing?

Comment: IMO if you are covering large gaps with quarter round you are no longer held to the standard of everything fitting perfectly without filler.  That standard is for people who want to do it WITHOUT quarter round!  You get a free pass.  What's your objection to filling and sanding?

Comment: If you can’t use putty go to the rental store and ask to rent a board stretcher. This is the only advice other than adding some filler or replacing the board with a longer one.

Comment: JAY613 - just want to do the best job possible

Comment: Ed Beal - board stretcher?   what does that do?

Comment: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Board%20Stretcher,  I expect they keep them next to the long weights, and striped paint.  (it's a fictional implement)

Answer (score 2):

If you have *gaps* in the corners where the miters are not tight, then *NO*, sanding down the miters won't make them fit better - it will make the trim pieces even shorter, *increasing* the size of the gaps.

---

Even the newest house isn't built with precisely 90° corners. Since yours is old enough to require that the floors be refinished, you can be reasonably assured that all for walls are *not* exactly 90° corners. In order to make the miters tight, the original carpenter adjusted each miter to match the precise angle of the corner - it's much more obvious that the miters aren't tight than that they aren't cut at exactly 45°, so that's how it's done.

If the miters were tight before you removed the trim but they're not tight now, then you have done your test fitting with the trim pieces in the wrong place. Rearrange the trim pieces until you get a nice tight fit.

NOTE: Since you have replaced the floor, you have (slightly or by a largish amount, depending on the difference in thickness between the old and new flooring) adjusted the height at which the trim now sits. If there are parts of the wall at the corner that aren't perfectly vertical (even slight enough that you can't feel it), it's possible that *no* arrangement of the trim will be able to get you back to the original nice, tight miters, simply because the trim is now sitting at a new spot on the wall and no longer matches the exact angles from before.

#### TL;DR:

- Rearrange the trim pieces until the miters fit tightly enough for your satisfaction.
- If you cannot find an arrangement of pieces that meets your standards (it's your house, you determine what you/spouse are satisfied with):

  - Replace pieces that don't match up well enough, or
  - Use wood putty to fill the gaps.